# Fragments inside ViewPager dissapear when orientation changes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-orientation

I have read several posts (http://tinyurl.com/pb8es74, http://tinyurl.com/p9pcfcv...) about this but cannot find a solution.

I have a MainActivity which loads a layout containing a ViewPager with three fragments (which have different layouts depending on orientation).

I have added this feature to the activity so it is not destroyed when the orientation changes as I might have some dialogs or popips opened:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
```

Therefore, I have overwritten the method "onConfigurationChanged" which just calls the method loadLayout, where everything regarding the view is made:

```
 private void loadLayout() {
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_main_activity);

    pager = (ViewPager) this.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setPageTransformer(true, new DepthPageTransformer());

    adapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(Fragment1.getInstance());
    adapter.addFragment(Fragment2.getInstance());
    adapter.addFragment(Fragment3.getInstance());

    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);

    //Media controllers
    imgMediaController= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.media_controller);

    imgMediaController.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            [...]
        }
    });

    imgVolumeController= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.volume_controller);
    gM.setImgVolumeController(imgVolumeController);

    imgVolumeController.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            [...]
        }
    });
}
```

The code for the fragments is equal:

```
public class FragmentNature extends Fragment {

private static FragmentNature instance;
private SoundManager sM;
private View rootView;
Hashtable<String, ImageButton> h_Images;
private Handler repeatUpdateHandler = new Handler();
private Toast volumeToast;


public static FragmentNature getInstance() {
    if (instance == null)
        instance = new FragmentNature();
    return instance;
}

public void nullInstance() {
    instance=null;
}

public FragmentNature(){
    h_Images=new Hashtable<String,ImageButton>();
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("Naturing", "On create->Estoy en el fragment nature");
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    sM=SoundManager.getInstance();
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    rootView=null;
    Log.d("Naturing", "On createView->Estoy en el fragment nature");
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nature, container, false);

    final ImageButton imgRain= (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.n_rain);
    h_Images.put("n_rain",imgRain);
    imgRain.setImageResource(R.drawable.n_rainsel);

    final ImageButton imgRiver= (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.n_river);
    imgRiver.setImageResource(R.drawable.n_riversel);

    final ImageButton imgWave= (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.n_wave);
    h_Images.put("n_wave",imgWave);
    imgWave.setImageResource(R.drawable.n_wavesel);

    final ImageButton imgWind= (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.n_wind);
    h_Images.put("n_wind", imgWind);
    imgWind.setImageResource(R.drawable.n_windsel);

    final ImageButton imgFire= (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.n_fire);
    h_Images.put("n_fire", imgFire);
    imgFire.setImageResource(R.drawable.n_firesel);

    final ImageButton imgTree= (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.n_tree);
    h_Images.put("n_tree", imgTree);
    imgTree.setImageResource(R.drawable.n_treesel);

    final ImageButton imgStorm= (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.n_storm);
    h_Images.put("n_storm", imgStorm);
    imgStorm.setImageResource(R.drawable.n_stormsel);

    final ImageButton imgDrop= (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.n_drop);
    h_Images.put("n_drop", imgDrop);
    imgDrop.setImageResource(R.drawable.n_dropsel);

    final ImageButton imgDeepSea= (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.n_deepsea);
    h_Images.put("n_deepsea", imgDeepSea);
    imgDeepSea.setImageResource(R.drawable.n_deepseasel);

    return rootView;
}

private boolean isNetworkAvailable(){
    Context context=ApplicationManager.getAppContext();
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager=
            (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo= connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}

public void changeImageStatus(String sound, int imgId){
    Log.d("Naturing", "FragmentNature::changeImageStatus  | sound= " + sound + "  imgId=" + imgId);
    h_Images.get(sound).setImageResource(imgId);
}
```

}

The problem is that when the orientation changes, the mainActivity layout is correctly loaded, but the viewPager is not. In fact it dissapears and nothing can be seen in its place. Anyway, the viewPager is there as I am able to go through it and reach the end (I know this because I can see the blue sign when you reach the end of a menu and so).

I have also tried to call the OncreateView method of the fragments but nothing changes.

Any idea?
Thanks and kind regards

**EDIT 1**

If I take out "pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);", after orientation changes, fragment 1 and fragment 3 are visible when I scroll the viewpager for a while, but fragment 2 does not appear in any case. I know it is not much but in case it gives a hint to anyone.

**EDIT 2**

If I take out the line in the Manifest, it works ok as it calls the onCreateView of the MainActivity and Fragment. But I need the line in the manifest.

Comment: May i know why you are using `DepthPAgeTransformer`... and post your Fragment code also

Comment: I use it just to make some special event when scrolling the pager. I removed it but still I have the problem

Comment: What is the need of creating rootview as global object and why are you making it as null.

Comment: I checked the other two and it was ok in them, I do not know why I had it like that. Anyway, it has nothing to do with the problem. Any other ideas?

Comment: Make that one as a local object, and try again may be it will work

Comment: No, it does not work

Answer (score 0):

In the end I did it with DialogFragments, because I needed to go ahead.
Anyway, it would be great if anyone knows anything about how to overcome the problem in the way I explained in the question for future developments.

Thanks